# CodeIgniter Email Sending problems

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm created this email sending form, it worked until I change the code to this (this is my controller):

```
public function sendMail()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'utf-8'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


    $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'));
    $this->email->to('mymail@gmail.com');
    $this->email->phone($this->input->post('phone'));
    $this->email->contact($this->input->post('contact'));
    $this->email->subject($this->input->post('subject'));
    $this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));


    if( $this->email->send() ){
        redirect ('/');
    } else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```

and the HTML/PHP part:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('Email/sendMail'); ?>" accept-charset="utf-8" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input name="first_name" type="text" id="name" size="30" placeholder="Név">
                            <br>
                            <input name="contact" type="text" id="contact" size="30" placeholder="Email">
                            <br>
                            <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" placeholder="Telefon">
                            <br>
                            <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="30" placeholder="Tárgy">
                            <br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <fieldset>
                            <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="20" id="message" placeholder="Üzenet, Kérdés, Kérés..."></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" name="submit" id="submit" value="Üzenet Elküldése">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

After Submit it gest a:
Message: Call to undefined method CI_Email::contact()
also in phone etc.

Thanks for the helps in advance!

Comment: post your complete error

Comment: There is no contact or phone method 
look@ http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no contact/phone method in email library. Should be a part of your message, so you need to do something like that:

```
$this->email->message($this->input->post("message") .
"<br><b>Phone:</b> " . $this->input->post("phone") . 
"<b><b>Contact:</b>" . $this->input->post("contact"));
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot!